# How to calculate the maximum of data bits for each QR code?

Tags: qr-code

Having some information for **QR version 40 (177*177 modules)** with correction level **L (7%  error correction)**

> **Version:** 40
>
> **Error Correction Level**: L
>
> **Data bits:** 23.648
>
> **Numeric Mode:** 7089
>
> **Alphanumeric Mode:**    4296
>
> **Byte Mode:** 2953

I don’t know about these points:

1. Does 1 module equal 1 bit?
2. How to calculate the maximum number of data bits in a QR code type? e.g Why do we have 23,648 for data bits?
3. How to convert data bits to Numeric/Alphanumeric in a QR code type? e.g. why do we have 7,089 for Numeric and 4,296 for Alphanumeric?

Thanks all!

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The derivation of the numbers to which you refer is a result of several distinct steps performed when generating the symbol described in detail by [ISO/IEC 18004](http://www.iso.org/iso/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=62021).

Any formula for the data capacity will be necessarily awkward and unenlightening since many of the parameters that determine the structure of QR Code symbols have been manually chosen and therefore implementations must generally resort to including tables of constants for these non-computed values.

**How to derive the number of usable data bits**

Essentially the total number of data modules for a chosen symbol version would be the total symbol area less any function pattern modules and format/version information modules:

`DataModules = Rows × Columns − ( FinderModules + AlignmentModules + TimingPatternModules ) − ( FormatInformationModules + VersionInformationModules )`

The values of these parameters are constants defined per symbol version.

Some of these data modules are then allocated to error correction purposes as defined by the chosen error correction level. What remains is the usable data capacity of the symbol found by treating each remaining module as a single bit:

`UsableDataBits = DataModules − ErrorCorrectionBits`

**How to derive the character capacity for each mode**

Encoding of the input data begins with a 4-bit mode indicator followed by a character count value whose length depends on the version of the symbol and the mode. Then the data is encoded according to the rules for the particular mode resulting in the following data compaction:

- **Numeric** Groups of 3 characters into 10 bits; 2 remainders into 7 bits; 1 remainder into 4 bits.
- **Alphanumeric** Groups of 2 characters into 11 bits; 1 remainder into 6 bits.
- **Byte** Each character into 8 bits.
- **Kanji** Each wide-character into 13 bits.

Although it does not affect the symbol capacity, for completeness I'll point out that a 4-bit terminator pattern is appended which may be truncated or omitted if there is insufficient capacity in the symbol. Any remaining data bits are then filled with a padding pattern.

**Worked Example**

Given a version 40 symbol with error correction level L.

The size is 177×177 = 31329 modules

There are three 8×8 finder patterns (192 modules), forty six 5×5 alignment patterns (1150 modules) and 272 timing modules, totalling 1614 function pattern modules.

There are also 31 format information modules and 36 version information modules, totalling 67 modules.

`DataModules = 31329 − 1614 − 67 = 29648`

Error correction level L dictates that there shall be 750 8-bit error correction codewords (6000 bits):

`UsableDataBits = 29648 − 6000 = 23648`

The character count lengths for a version 40 symbol are specified as follows:

- **Numeric** 14 bits.
- **Alphanumeric** 13 bits.
- **Byte** 16 bits.
- **Kanji** 12 bits.

Consider alphanumeric encoding. From the derived `UsableDataBits` figure of 23648 bits available we take 4 bits for the mode indicator and 13 bits for the character count leaving just **23631** for the actual alphanumeric data (and truncatable terminator and padding.)

You quoted 4296 as the alphanumeric capacity of a version 40-L QR Code symbol. Now 4296 alphanumeric characters becomes exactly 2148 groups of two characters each converted to 11 bits, producing 23628 data bits which is just inside our symbol capacity. However 4297 characters would produce 2148 groups with one remainder character that would be encoded into 6 bits, which produces 23628 + 6 bits overall – exceeding the 23631 bits available. So 4296 characters is clearly the correct alphanumeric capacity of a type 40-L QR Code.

Similarly for numeric encoding we have 23648−4−14 = 23630 bits available. Your quoted 7089 is exactly 2363 groups of three characters each converted to 10 bits, producing 23630 bits – exactly filling the bits available. Clearly any further characters would not fit so we have found our limit.

**Caveat**

Whilst the character capacity can be derived using the above procedure in practise QR Code permits encoding the input using multiple modes within a single symbol and a decent QR Code generator will switch between modes as often as necessary to optimise the overall data density. This makes the whole business of considering the capacity limits much less useful for open applications since they only describe the pathological case.

Comment: Your explantions are very clear and helpful. Thanks @Terry Burton very much !