# Calculate minimum QRcode version from input data

Tags: qr-code

I started to study ISO/IEC 18004 - the "QRcode specification".

When encoding data as a QRcode (generating a QRcode), the following information must be specified:

- Mode (what kind of data, eg `numeric`, `alphanumeric`, `binary`, ...)
- Error correction level (`L`, `M`, `Q` or `H`)
- Version (the "size" of the QRcode)

I am looking for a mathematical (equation) way of determining the version requires to hold the provided data with the specified mode and error correction level. The standard itself contains a look-up table which is also available from various web sources such as [this](https://www.qrcode.com/en/about/version.html) or [this](https://www.thonky.com/qr-code-tutorial/error-correction-table) (they are just look-up tables).

A quote from [this very related SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34465106/how-to-calculate-the-maximum-of-data-bits-for-each-qr-code):

> Any formula for the data capacity will be necessarily awkward and unenlightening since many of the parameters that determine the structure of QR Code symbols have been manually chosen and therefore implementations must generally resort to including tables of constants for these non-computed values.

As per my current understanding of the standard, it should be possible to determine the data capacity (and therefore minimum version) required based on the input data, mode and ECC level. The answer even expressed the calculations for the maximum capacity:

> `DataModules = Rows × Columns − ( FinderModules + AlignmentModules + TimingPatternModules ) − ( FormatInformationModules + VersionInformationModules )`

> `UsableDataBits = DataModules − ErrorCorrectionBits`

I don't understand where the "awkwardness" that would lead to resorting to a look-up table originates from? As per my understanding sizes of timing pattern etc. are fixed per version.

Could somebody further explain this?

Answer (score 1):

zxing provides an implementation for that:

https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/qrcode/encoder/Encoder.java

```
/**
* Decides the smallest version of QR code that will contain all of the 
provided data.
*
* @throws WriterException if the data cannot fit in any version
*/
private static Version recommendVersion(ErrorCorrectionLevel ecLevel,
                                        Mode mode,
                                        BitArray headerBits,
                                        BitArray dataBits)
```

The Encoder class provides the algorithm ("mathematical way") of determining the minimum version you are looking for.

If this implementation is in any kind "awkward" or not, I cannot answer.

Comment: Gotta love the comment in that implementation: `// Use that guess to calculate the right version. I am still not sure this works in 100% of cases.` :-D

Anyway, thanks for sharing, much appreciated! I'll have a proper look at this and will report back accordingly.

Comment: Since zxing is possibly the most used library for generating and reading QR-codes and the implementation is still the way it is, there is a chance, that even if it doesn't work in 100% of cases, it works in a sufficient part of cases. Depending on the interpretation of "works": it might as well be, that zxing plays safe and in some cases a slightly higher version is calculated, than exaclty the smallest version all data fits in.